Equality of angles as condition for tangent of a circle
Assume we have the following diagram:
Let vector $D$ denote the sum of two vectors $V_{\oplus}$ and $V_{\ominus}$ (shown with the  parallelogram law). Let $V_{\oplus}, V_{\ominus}$ be such that $\frac{|V_{\oplus}|}{|V_{\ominus}|} = \frac{Bp}{Ap}$. Since $\angle tsp = \angle ApB$, we get that the triangle $\triangle tsp$ is similar to $\triangle BpA$. Therefore we get that the angles denoted by $\cdot$ and $\odot$ are equal. Prove that this implies that $D$ is tangent to the circle.

My attempt:
Let's denote $\angle ApB=\alpha$.
I've labelled $\angle ABp$ as $\gamma$, and noticed $\gamma = \pi - (\alpha + \odot)$. I couldn't get further.  I think I'm missing some circle-related theorem, possibly about tangents.
The diagram is from Tristan Needham Visual Complex Analysis, p. 517.

This is called alternate segment theorem. See https://www.timdevereux.co.uk/maths/geompages/proof7.php

Let $O$ be the centre of the circle and $\angle OpA=\angle OAp=\alpha$.
Then $\angle pOA=180-2\alpha$ and by inscribed angles on $pA$, $\angle pBA=90+\alpha$, so $\alpha+\odot+\angle BpA=90$.
